# large video html5 background

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have an html5 video as a background here: http://expedition-design.com/dev/2ndmile/vid_test.html

```
<video id="video_background" preload="metadata" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0">
```

The video is quite large (75mb or so) and a high quality (not certain if HD).

My question is are there any ways to have it load faster/smoother? - for me on a wireless connection it has a hitch in it like a slow loading video.

Any thoughts or ideas would be most welcomed.

Comment: You probably want to [reduce the bitrate itself](http://superuser.com/questions/4244/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-a-huge-mp4-video). This should be a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Just FYI, Google Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107 m (newest at the moment) failed to load the video. It's just a black page with "Hello World"

Comment: Considering that the video is 75mb in size and goes for 59 seconds, a little bit of maths shows you that the video needs to be downloaded at 1.3MBps+ (thats megabytes, not megabits) to stream smoothly. If the server delivers the video slower, or the client downloads it slower, the video is guaranteed to pause for buffering.  As suggested, you need to lower the bitrate drastically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to go with clipping the file, and lowering the bit-rate in an effort to speed this up.

Thanks for all the replies.

----Follow up - lowering it 420 (from 1080) has it where it needs to be size-wise

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's an option for you, but I tend to recommend someone else do the video hosting (eg: [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/), [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com)).

- Dedicated video websites have a large viewing network already built - free exposure for your content
- They handle downsizing / quality control for slow connections
- Upload a HQ video one time, everyone sees the best they can (even if not HQ)
- Easy to embed on your website